# CSS menu not working properly in IE7

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7

I have got a css menu over here, http://fitzwilliamcardclub.com/ and it is working just fine in all except IE7 (tested ok with FF, Chrome, Safari, IE8 & IE9, Opera). In IE7 the dropdown menu is hiding behind the main background as there is a small hint that the menu is expanded on the hover but it is going behind the main background starting just below the menu. I have been trying on this for more that three days now but it could not help with this and it is  really frustrating. I tried almost all things what i could thought of, setting z-index of menu  elements and of background etc. but it does not work. Can someone take a look at the site navigation menu at http://fitzwilliamcardclub.com/ and post a fix, if it possible at all. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give #main a position:relative and set the menu li's to have a higher z-index than #main.

Answer (score 0):

For IE7, giving the parent element a higher z-index actual fixes the bug. I'd used such a fix on http://www.skinwerein.com/.

This might be helpful to you. http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/